# JNDI Lookup and PARENT_LAST with Websphere

Tags: java, url, websphere, classloader, jndi

I'm experiencing a side effect with the following scenario:

I'm looking up a URL via JNDI in a J2EE 5.0 web application running on Websphere Application Server 8.5.5 this way:

```
URL jndiLmcUrl = null;

try {

    Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
    jndiLmcUrl = (URL) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/url/ENLMC);

} catch (NamingException ne) {

    String message = "Unable to found middleware configuration file specified with Jndi property java:/comp/env/url/" + systemPropertyName + " as URI/URL. Trying as system property";

    LOG.error(message);

}
```

My web.xml configuration is:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>url/ENLMC</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>java.net.URL</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

In addition i have defined the URL Resource using WAS Console under Resources/URL/Urls with server scope.

ALL IS WORKING FINE as expected.

But, for some reasons (primarily WS Metro usage) i've to move the application to PARENT_LAST using MyApplication/ManageModules/Class loaded with  local class loader first (parent last).

After this operation the JNDI lookup fails raising a Naming Exception.

Thank you for your precious help.

Comment: You need to show the naming exception or no one will be able to help.  It would probably also be helpful to list the JARs included in your application since you're probably including something you should not.

Comment: +1 to what Brett said.  Replacing exception messages with your own message is typically not a good idea unless you know exactly what can be going wrong.  Appending `ne.getMessage()` to your `message` would be a good idea in this case.

Comment: Try creating a MANIFEST.MF in your EJB jar's ejbModule/META-INF folder. Include all EAR library jar names in it.